# Regex find and replace to build SQL (join) on statement?

Tags: sql, regex, visual-studio-code, vim

I'm using vscodevim and I have

```
list of variables
```

and I want to turn it into

```
a.list = b.list and a.of = b.of and a.variables = b.variables
```

for an SQL join.

I used the find and replace regex

```
:s/\w+/a.& = b.& and/g
```

but obviously it results in

```
a.list = b.list and a.of = b.of and a.variables = b.variables and
```

Can I modify the regex to remove/skip that final `and` without using a second separate find and replace?

Comment: Do this in two steps: 1) `\w+\b(?!\W*$)` and your replacement, and then 2) `\w+(?=\W*$)` => `a.& = b.&` (non-Vim)

Comment: In Vim, try `:s/\(\w\+\)\(\W*$\)\@!\|\(\w\+\)\(\W*$\)\@=/\=submatch(1) == '' ? 'a.'.submatch(1).' = b.'.submatch(1).' and' : 'a.'.submatch(2).' = b.'.submatch(2).' and'/g`

Comment: Thanks, the second one makes sense but what if I don't know how long the list will be? Like it could be three words as in my example, but it could be more or less words. edit: looking again, maybe submatch(2) isn't the second word, it is the final word with no space after it?

Comment: This is the point where I'd give up on regex and just delete the last word from the line.

Comment: submatch(2) is the last word.

Comment: Ok cool. I can't get it to work in vscode vim though. I know vscode vim doesn't have to escape every special character, and submatch(1) is just \1, but I don't know if it has anything like if submatch(1) equals ''  then replace with one thing, else replace with another...

Comment: What Wiktor proposed uses `\=` to evaluate the replacement as an expression. This uses `submatch(1)` instead of `\1` and allows for the ternary operator `condition ? true-case : else-case`. It's not just a question of escaping special characters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my comment of deleting the last word was aimed at the original question, not your comment. Not sure if you replied to OP or me (or both). I must admit I haven't tried your regex but it looks good enough and I trust you to get a regex right.

Comment: Just delete the extra ` and` manually.

Comment: if you can do conditional replacement try something like: `\w+(?=$|(\b))` and replace with `a.$0 = b.$0 ${1:+and}`. This applies the "and" only if the matched word is not at the end of line. See: https://regex101.com/r/ntq2UT/latest

Answer (score 0):

You can give multiple commands using `|` as a separator. If you want to use `|` in an argument of regex, precede it with `\`.

```
:s /\w\+/a.& = b.& and/g | s /\s\+and$//
```